# Kerkis Sans family on demand

Tags: fonts

In the following MWE my main font is `txfonts` and I also loaded `kerkis` font.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
ΑΒΓΔ
\end{document}
```

I would like to use `txfonts` as main font and change when needed to `kerkis`.Is there a way to use `kerkis sans` locally?

Comment: Do you want to load them for Greek math letters, for Greek body text, for headers, or what purpose?

Comment: For greek text to be used for titles, chapters and sections mostly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to load Kerkis Sans as the sans-serif text font, you can

```
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{maksf}
```

And then use the `\sffamily` or `\textsf` commands.

If you want to use Kerkis Sans for Greek letters in math mode, you can do this with

```
\usepackage[LGRgreek]{mathastext}
\MTgreekfont{maksf}\Mathastext
```

If you want to use a different font as your English font and switch to Kerkis/Kerkis Sans for Greek—I do not recommend this for Times and Kerkis Sans because the fonts do not match at all—you can set it up as a LGR substitution with `substitutefont`:

```
\documentclass[greek,english]{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tgschola}
\usepackage{substitutefont}

\substitutefont{LGR}{\rmdefault}{mak}
\substitutefont{LGR}{\sfdefault}{maksf}

\begin{document}
abc \textgreek{ελληνικού}
\end{document}
```

[image: TG Schola/Kerkis sample]

In the unlikely event that you wanted to use Kerkis Sans in addition to a different sans-serif body font, you can switch to it with `\fontfamily{maksf}\selectfont`.

Comment: I want to be more specific. The main reason I want to use both fonts is to let `txfontsb` be my main font and to use `kerkis sans` for chapter, section and paragraph titles. For many years I've been using `xelatex` for my documents and to change font is as simple as calling the command `\font\myfont="KerkisSans"`. I was hoping to find a similar way to do it in `pdflatex`.

Comment: I also get a Tex capacity error when using `\substitutefont` command.

Comment: @mac I added a MWE with `substitutefont` that works in PDFLaTeX on TeX Live 2020.

Comment: Your MWE works fine. The error occurs when using `kerkis` for some reason. I also use Texlive 2020

Comment: @mac If you load `kerkis` as your default fonts, you should just be able to use its LGR font without any substitution. You tried to substitute Kerkis with itself.